# Сессия истекла - удалить пользователя codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Помогите реализовать функцию удаления аккаунта из phpmyadmin по истечению 48 часов 
Мне нужно чтобы сессия хранилась 48 часов и после истечении сессии удалялся аккаунт из бд
Например дана функция

```
public function start(){
        $loged = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        if($loged == TRUE){
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $data = $this->data;
            $current_stage = $this->user->get_current_stage_by_user_id($user_id);
            $data['current_stage'] = $current_stage['user_current_stage'];
            /*$insert_stage['user_current_stage'] = 'part1';
            $this->user->update_user_stage($user_id, $insert_stage);*/
            $this->load->view('start.php',$data);
        }
        else{
            redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Надо чтобы был редирект и удаление аккаунта. Не получается реализовать такую функцию
Можно просто задать время жизни аккаунта , после того , как залогинился на сайт

Comment: Мне кажется правильне было бы записывать временную метку для пользователя а потом её анализировать.

Comment: Можете помочь с этим?

Comment: А ID Пользователя всегда новый или может быть повторяющийся ?

Comment: без разницы , лучше новый

Comment: С новым быстрее будет , я думаю)

Comment: Временная метка в sql уже есть

Comment: user_created_date

Answer (score 0):

Так не совсем понятно. 
Смотри если id пользователя всегда новое то не нужно его записывать. Просто установи время сесси и если он не истекло тогда не делай редирект на /.
Если пользоватьль в течении 48 часов может повторятся тогда алгоритм следующий.

1. Открываем Сессию.
2. Берём ID пользователя и проверям его на наличие в базе.
   2.1 Если ID Пользователя новый тогда записываем его в базу и записываем Время. 
   2.2 Если ID пользователя не новое и время не истекол тогда тогда перенправляем куда нужно 
   2.3 есди ID пользователя не новое и время истекло тогда пренаправляем на \

Нужен ещё 1 дополнительный класс или скрипт который бы запускался бы в cron или scheduler.
Его задача следующая взять текуще время и проверить пользователе у которых истекло время. Если время истекло тогда удалть пользователя.

Comment: А можно сделать так чтобы  по окончанию времении сессии , удалялся пользователь

Comment: В голову ничего не приходит кроме реализации собственного класса scheduler в который  бы передовался параметр ID пользователя и дата удаления пользователя и он бы на основании этих параметров бы удалял бы пользователей из базы, но это сильно усложняет схему.